# Benchmarking Sorting Algorithms Java; Average Run Times are incorrect

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, runtime

While I understand the following method for benchmarking isn't ideal, I am working on benchmarking sorting algorithms to help better understand algorithms and data structures.

I want to list the average run times of a "large" n 500000 and small "n" size array 50, but my averages are always increasing.

I am unsure of where I went wrong:

```
    public class BenchmarkingAlgorithms
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int[] largeUnsortedArray = largeArrayWithRandomInts(500000);

        
      
        bubbleSort(largeUnsortedArray);
        
        selectionSort(largeUnsortedArray);
        insertionSort(largeUnsortedArray);
        benchmarkQuickSort(largeUnsortedArray);
        benchmarkMergeSort(largeUnsortedArray);
        
        
        int[] smallUnsortedArray = smallArrayWithRandomInts(50);

        bubbleSort(smallUnsortedArray);
        selectionSort(smallUnsortedArray);
        insertionSort(smallUnsortedArray);
        benchmarkQuickSort(smallUnsortedArray);
        benchmarkMergeSort(smallUnsortedArray);
    }

    /**
     * Sorting an array of ints in ascending order using bubbleSort
     * Best-Case Complexity: O(n), Average Complexity: O(n^2), Worst-Case Complexity: O(n^2)
     * O(n) is achieved in Best-Case (already sorted array) using the alreadySorted flag
     * @param array
     * @return
     */
    static int[] bubbleSort(int[] array)
    {
         int bubbleSortTime[] = new int[500];
          int x, y;
          for (x = 0; x< 500; x++) {
              
          
        int temp;
        boolean alreadySorted = true;
        long start = System.nanoTime();
       
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
          

            for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++)
            {

                if (array[j] > array[j + 1])
                {
                    alreadySorted = false;
                    temp = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
                }
                
            }
            if (alreadySorted == true)
            {
                break;
            }
            
        }
            long end = System.nanoTime();
            
            long bubbleSortRunTime = end - start;
            
            bubbleSortTime[x] = (int) bubbleSortRunTime;
            x++;
            

        }
        // getting array length
        int length = bubbleSortTime.length;
 
        // default sum value.
        int sum = 0;
 
        // sum of all values in array using for loop
        for (int i = 0; i < bubbleSortTime.length; i++) {
            sum += bubbleSortTime[i];
        }
 
        double average = sum / length;
         
        System.out.println("Average of array : "+average + " nano seconds.");
 
    }
        
          

        return array;
          
    
    }

    /**
     * Sorting an array of ints in ascending order using selectionSort
     * Best-Case Complexity: O(n^2), Average Complexity: O(n^2), Worst-Case Complexity: O(n^2)
     * @param array
     * @return
     */
    static int[] selectionSort(int[] array)
    {
        
         int selectionSortTime[] = new int[500];
         int x, y;
         for (x = 0; x< 500; x++) {
          
        int min;
        int pos = 0;
        long start = System.nanoTime();
     
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
            {
               
                min = array[i];
                for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++)
                {
                    if (array[j] < min)
                    {
                        min = array[j];
                        pos = j;
                    }
                }
                array[pos] = array[i];
                array[i] = min;
            }
           

        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        
        long selectionSortRunTime = end - start;
        
        selectionSortTime[x] = (int) selectionSortRunTime;
        x++;
        

    
    // getting array length
    int length = selectionSortTime.length;

    // default sum value.
    int sum = 0;

    // sum of all values in array using for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < selectionSortTime.length; i++) {
        sum += selectionSortTime[i];
    }

    double average = sum / length;
     
    System.out.println("Average of array : "+average + " nano seconds.");

}
    
        
        return array;
    }

    /**
     * Sorting an array of ints in ascending order using insertionSort
     * Best-Case Complexity: O(n), Average Complexity: O(n^2), Worst-Case Complexity: O(n^2)
     * @param array
     * @return
     */
    static int[] insertionSort(int[] array)
    {
        
        int insertionSortTime[] = new int[500];
      int x, y;
        for (x = 0; x< 500; x++) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        int j;

       
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
            {
             

                int key = array[i];

                for (j = i - 1; (j >= 0) && (key < array[j]); j--)
                {
                    array[j + 1] = array[j];
                }
                array[j + 1] = key;
            }
          

        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();
    long insertionSortRunTime = end - start;
        
        insertionSortTime[x] = (int) insertionSortRunTime;
        x++;
        

    
    // getting array length
    int length = insertionSortTime.length;

    // default sum value.
    int sum = 0;

    // sum of all values in array using for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < insertionSortTime.length; i++) {
        sum += insertionSortTime[i];
    }

    double average = sum / length;
     
    System.out.println("Average of array : "+average + " nano seconds.");

}
        

        return array;
    }

    /**
     * Sorting an array of ints in ascending order using quickSort
     * Best-Case Complexity: O(n log(n)), Average Complexity: O(n log(n)), Worst-Case Complexity: O(n^2))
     * @param array
     * @return
     */
    static void quickSort(int[] array, int low, int high)
    {
        
        int pivot = array[low + ((high - low) / 2)];
        int i = low;
        int j = high;


            while (i <= j)
            {

                while (array[i] < pivot)
                {
                    i++;
                }
                while (array[j] > pivot)
                {
                    j--;
                }
                if (i <= j)
                {
                    int temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
                    i++;
                    j--;
                }
            }

            if (low < j)
            {
                quickSort(array, low, j);
            }

            if (i < high)
            {
                quickSort(array, i, high);
            }
        }

    /**
     * Helping method to benchmark quick sort's execution time
     * @param array
     */
    static void benchmarkQuickSort(int[] array)
    { 
        int quickSortTime[] = new int[500];
          int x, y;
          for (x = 0; x< 500; x++) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        quickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        long quickSortRunTime = end - start;
        
        quickSortTime[x] = (int) quickSortRunTime;
        x++;
        

    
    // getting array length
    int length = quickSortTime.length;

    // default sum value.
    int sum = 0;

    // sum of all values in array using for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < quickSortTime.length; i++) {
        sum += quickSortTime[i];
    }

    double average = sum / length;
     
    System.out.println("Average of array : "+average + " nano seconds.");

}
        
    }

    /**
     * Sorting an array of ints in ascending order using mergeSort
     * Best-Case Complexity: O(n log(n)), Average Complexity: O(n log(n)), Worst-Case Complexity: O(n log(n)))
     * @param array
     * @return
     */
    public static int[] mergeSort(int[] array)
    {
        if (array.length == 1)
        {
            return array;
        }

        int[] array1 = new int[(array.length/2)];
        int[] array2 = new int[(array.length-array1.length)];

        System.arraycopy(array, 0, array1, 0, array1.length);
        System.arraycopy(array, array1.length, array2, 0, array2.length);

        mergeSort(array1);
        mergeSort(array2);

        merge(array1, array2, array);
        return array;
    }

    /**
     * Merges 2 sorted arrays of ints
     * @param array1
     * @param array2
     * @param mergedArray
     * @return
     */
    static void merge(int[] array1, int[] array2, int[] mergedArray)
    {
        int array1Index = 0;
        int array2Index = 0;
        int pos = 0;
        while ((array1Index < array1.length) && (array2Index < array2.length))
        {
            if (array1[array1Index] < array2[array2Index])
            {
                mergedArray[pos] = array1[array1Index];
                array1Index++;
                pos++;
            } else
            {
                mergedArray[pos] = array2[array2Index];
                array2Index++;
                pos++;
            }
        }

        if (array1Index < array2Index)
        {
            System.arraycopy(array1, array1Index, mergedArray, pos, array1.length - array1Index);
        }
        else if (array2Index < array1Index) ;
        {
            System.arraycopy(array2, array2Index, mergedArray, pos, array2.length - array2Index);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Helping method to benchmark merge sort's execution time
     * @param array
     */
    static void benchmarkMergeSort(int[] array)
    {
        int mergeSortTime[] = new int[500];
      int x, y;
        for (x = 0; x< 500; x++) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        mergeSort(array);
        long end = System.nanoTime();
  long quickSortRunTime = end - start;
        
        mergeSortTime[x] = (int) quickSortRunTime;
        x++;
        

    
    // getting array length
    int length = mergeSortTime.length;

    // default sum value.
    int sum = 0;

    // sum of all values in array using for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < mergeSortTime.length; i++) {
        sum += mergeSortTime[i];
    }

    double average = sum / length;
     
    System.out.println("Average of array : "+average + " nano seconds.");
        }

}

    /**
     * Creates and returns an array with random ints
     * @param size the size of the array to be created
     * @return
     */
    static int[] largeArrayWithRandomInts(int size)
    {
        int[] largeArray = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            largeArray[i] = (int) (Math.random() * Math.random() * 500000);
        }
        return largeArray;
    }
    
    static int[] smallArrayWithRandomInts(int size)
    {
        int[] smallArray = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            smallArray[i] = (int) (Math.random() * Math.random() * 50);
        }
        return smallArray;
    }

    /**
     * Prints the elements of  one dimensional array of type int
     * @param array
     */
    static void printArray(int[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

I appreciate any insight.  Always ready to learn something new.

Comment: `double average = sum / length;` Why are you printing this out as the average time?

Comment: This is because I was trying to assign each timing of the sort to a space in the array and I wanted to average the array.   I want to simply print out the average runtime of each of these algorithms for the Large n and the Small n.

Comment: I want it to run 500 iterations, of each n size.  500000 and 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things going wrong in your method.

1. You are calculating and printing the in-between times by taking the average of 500 elements in `bubbleSortTime`. For the first run, instead of dividing by `bubbleSortTime.length` (which is 500), you should be dividing by `x + 1` to get the average of the runs that you have done so far.
2. You are timing each run separately, rounding to roughly 50 nanoseconds due to how `System.nanoTime()` works (see javadocs). What you should do is store the start time to a variable, then run the code that you want to time X times within a loop (100-1000 times is often sufficient, more runs will give a more precise result), then record the end time and finally divide the time elapsed by X to get the average runtime of the timed code.
3. Before starting to time your code, you should run the timed code at least once. This will cause all classes and required system libraries to be loaded, which can be a one-time slightly slower operation.

Comment: Ok so for 1) I should change this length to x +1?
        double average = sum / length;

Comment: I also thought I am storing each time into the array and then averaging the array.  Is this inaccurate?  I just wanted to find the average of each algorithm with a large n and a small n.  I keep printing random averages, however, that are negative and it takes a long time.  Is this usual?

Comment: Point 1 tells the main reason why your current times are not correct (and increasing). Points 2 and 3 tell how you should do it to get reasonable results, where point 3 could even be skipped if you make X large enough. So purely following point 2, you will only be timing X runs of the algorithm, and you compute the average from that. As you mentioned, that is more accurate because you round the time only once in 100-1000 runs, rather than 100-1000 times.